# Writing WordPress errors in STDOUT instead of debug.log?

Tags: php, wordpress, logging

My WordPress app is running on an ECS instance, and I also have CloudWatch set up for basic logging info.

This is all ok when everything is running fine, but when I have an error, all I see in my logs is something like

> x.x.x.x - - [21/Jan/2019:08:03:00 + 0000] "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1" 400 5 ....

Which happened when I created a new user, but there was an error. Which one, I have no idea.

So I'd like to output any errors that happen in `STDOUT` so that I can see them in my regular logs ([the twelve factor app - logging](https://12factor.net/logs)).

I was also thinking of implementing monolog, but that seems like it would take too much time, and I need something quick.

From digging in the WP core code I see that in the `wp-includes/load.php` I have

```
if ( WP_DEBUG_LOG ) {
  ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
  ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );
}
```

So the `error_log` writes errors and notices in the `debug.log` by default.

Can I just override this with something like

```
ini_set( 'error_log', fwrite( STDOUT, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' ) );
```

in my plugin or in my `wp-config.php`? Or is there something else I need to do? In general, I'd like to avoid creating the `debug.log` file all-together, and just output errors to `STDOUT`.

### EDIT

Ok, so putting the above code in `wp-config.php` won't work, as I get

> Use of undefined constant STDOUT
>
> Use of undefined constant WP_CONTENT_DIR

and

> :  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

warnings...

Comment: Plugins are loaded at a later point in time so you can simple add a new `ini_set` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually code is changed, so `define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/dev/stdout');` into wp-config.php should be enough:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    if ( WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY ) {
        ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    } elseif ( null !== WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY ) {
        ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
    }

    if ( in_array( strtolower( (string) WP_DEBUG_LOG ), array( 'true', '1' ), true ) ) {
        $log_path = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log';
    } elseif ( is_string( WP_DEBUG_LOG ) ) {
        $log_path = WP_DEBUG_LOG;
    } else {
        $log_path = false;
    }

    if ( $log_path ) {
        ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
        ini_set( 'error_log', $log_path );
    }
} else {
    error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer, this looks 'more correct' than my answer 

Answer (score 3):

So this apparently did the trick:

```
function overwrite_error_log() {
  ini_set( 'error_log', '/dev/stdout' ); // phpcs:ignore
}

add_action( 'init', 'overwrite_error_log', 10 );
```

Thanks to Sarah Pantry for providing the snippet on Facebook :)

Comment: setting this in wp-config didn't help. I put this in the functions.php in the theme folder. putting it in the root php of a plugin also worked

Comment: You cannot add this in the `wp-config.php`, because you need to have action hooks loaded, and those are loaded after `wp-config.php`. This is why you need to add this either in your plugin or theme :)